# File '1' in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I found I have files named `1` with zero size all over the hard drive. Especially in frequently used directories. They are created again even if I delete them. I think it maybe has something to do with Vim or terminal (I use iTerm2 with zsh) generally.

What do you think? What creates this files and why?

Comment: If this happened to me, the first thing I'd look for is to make sure I don't have a screwup in one of my shell startup files or other shell scripts. I'd be afraid one of my scripts (or command aliases or shell functions) has a bug that's doing this. Like I meant to type `touch $1` somewhere in a script, but actually put `touch 1`.

Comment: For all we know, alternatively, you have some idiosyncratic alias or shell function for some favourite command in which you've mis-spelled `2>&1`.  Or a friend with an odd sense of humour once set up a wacky `launchd` job.  There really is no way for people around the world to do any more than guess at what causes this.  We don't have magical remote access powers to your machine to investigate, and no way from the meagre information given to select from the wide range of possible explanations, from the mischievous to the humourous.

Comment: Another possibility is a shell script/function/etc containing something like `if [ $# > 1 ]` ... in which case the shell will treat the `> 1` part as a redirect to a file named "1" (and the `[` command doesn't print anything, so the file winds up empty).

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally managed to create '1' files in the past by using vim. I always use `:w!` to save a file which forces an overwrite without asking. When I was in a rush, I sometimes entered `:w1` instead by failing to press the shift key. This will create a file named '1'. But I can not explain why the files always have a size of 0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm afraid that this isn't my case. I use `w!` very rarely and my keyboard layout defines `!` without shift as +.